# I want to cascade multiple Dropdown lists using mvc 4 razor in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

In this MVC application I've created cascading dropdown list i.e it will first populate countries list and after selecting country jquery's onchange event is called which will fetch the further states from the controller which further gets those data by edmx entity model in database.i have used ajax request to call the JSON method in this.After selecting states the new dropdown list would get activated for selecting Cities.Whenever I select countries from the drop down an alertbox pops out and says states retrieving failed.[object][object] also I didn't create relationship between tables as foreign key is that necessary

Location Controller:-

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class LocationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Location/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities();
            ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(db.tblCountries, "CountryID", "CountryName");
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetState(string id)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var stateList = this.Getstatevalue(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            var stateData = stateList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.StateName,
                Value = m.StateID.ToString(),
            });
            return Json(stateData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public IList<tblState> Getstatevalue(int CountryId)
        {
           TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities();

            return db.tblStates.Where(m => m.CountryID == CountryId).ToList();
        }

        public JsonResult GetCity(string id)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> cities = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var cityList = this.Getcityvalue(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            var cityData = cityList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.CityName,
                Value = m.CityID.ToString(),
            });
            return Json(cityData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public IList<tblCity> Getcityvalue(int StateId)
        {
            TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities();

            return db.tblCities.Where(m => m.StateID == StateId).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml view

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeData</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Country")<br />
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewBag.Country as SelectList, "-- Please Select a Country  --", new { style = "width:150px", @id = "Country" })
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <br />
            @Html.Label("State")<br />
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("State", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "-- Please select a State --",
                        new { style = "width:150px", @class = "dropdown1" })
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <br />
            @Html.Label("City")<br />
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("City", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "-- Please select a city --",
                        new { style = "width:150px", @class = "dropdown2", @id = "City" })
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="button" onclick="ddlInsert()" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

javascript code :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // this is Country Dropdown Selectedchange event 
        $("#Country").change(function () {
            $("#State").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Getstates")', // here we are Calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#Country").val() },
                // Get Selected Country ID. 

                success: function (states) {
                    $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                        $("#State").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' +
                             state.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert(' states retrieving fail.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })

        $("#State").change(function () {
            $("#City").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCities")', // here we are Calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#State").val() },
                // Get Selected Country ID. 

                success: function (cities) {
                    $.each(cities, function (i, city) {
                        $("#City").append('<option value="' + city.Value + '">' +
                             city.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert(' city retrieving fail.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

[image: edmx diagram chart]

When I select a country in it No state gets loaded or populated into the dropdown list for states.

Comment: Go through [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/cascading-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) and [THIS](http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com/2013/04/cascading-dropdowns-in-aspnet-mvc3.html)

Comment: @Vikrant Sir i didn't created foreign key on fields used in other table that belong to another table is it the reason that it's not able to fetch states for that selected country